# Javascript Function to setTimeout and when a button on page is clicked cancel the timeout and proceed with the remaining functions?

Tags: javascript

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>

  <center>
    <b> This is My Virtual Pet!</b>
  </center>
  <center> <img id="target" src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/14623/images/magazine_hero/WW188829.jpg?1509653431" width="300" height="250" />

    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage()" value=" Scroll Through Emotions" /> </center>

  <br>
  <center>
    <input type="button" onclick="TimeoutStop()" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="1,2" value="Feed">
    <input type="button" onclick="TimeoutStop()" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="3,4,5" value="Pet">
    <input type="button" onclick="TimeoutStop()" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="3,0,4" value="Play">
  </center>


  <script>
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var counter = 0;
    var myVar;
    var myRhino = [
      "https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/14623/images/magazine_hero/WW188829.jpg?1509653431",

      "https://img04.deviantart.net/0594/i/2010/261/5/6/happy_rhino_by_ammut88-d2z0sto.jpg",

      "https://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large-5/angry-rhino-daniel-eskridge.jpg",

      "https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1340/1368093048_fa7ef85a5a_z.jpg?zz=1",

      "https://images.fineartamerica.com/images/artworkimages/mediumlarge/1/hungry-rhino-james-sarjeant.jpg",

      "http://m.rgbimg.com/cache1nulfB/users/z/za/zatrokz/600/meRoKDQ.jpg",

      "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R_zz1GEkEk4/maxresdefault.jpg",
    ];

        myVar = setTimeout("TimeoutImg()",2000);

    function changeImage(btn) {
      if (!btn) {
        counter += 1;
        target.src = myRhino[counter % myRhino.length];
      } else {
        var data = btn.getAttribute('data-values');
        var pics = JSON.parse("[" + data + "]"); // Convert string of numbers to an array
        var num = pics.shift(); // remove index 0 from array and store it in num
        pics.push(num); // Add what was previously at index 0 to end of array
        target.src = myRhino[num];
        counter = num;
        btn.setAttribute('data-values', pics.join(','));
      }
    }
      function TimeoutImg(){
            target.src = myRhino[6];
        }

        function TimeoutStop(){
            clearTimeout(myVar);
        }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</HTML>
```

This is the new code with the timeout function. How come when I click the button the timeout stops but It doesn't let me change any pictures on click.

I am trying to have the picture change in 10 seconds after the page opens if no buttons are clicked but if a button is clicked have the timer stop and proceed normallyy by clicked each of the three action buttons and having the image change.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish with this code.  Is each button supposed to be picking the next pic in the array, a random pic from the array, or a specific pic from the array?  and if it is specific pics, how are you identifying which ones are which, aside from their non-uniform URL?

Comment: How would I got about have a specific picture chosen? Am I able to give them an ID while they are in the array?

Comment: @Katie.Sun for one of the buttons, yes, but there are 3 other buttons with no code at all written for their functions.  it's not really clear what they want for the other 3, but it would seem they want something different, since they have different function names....

Comment: @Katie.Sun Yes I have the pictures looping but When one of the three buttons I have feed, pet, or play are clicked how would I have them change to a certain image in that array? Am I able to give them an id in the array

Comment: You can access the array the same way you access it with the counter.

Comment: @Claies I updated the post. I want the three other buttons to have their own function to Change to a certain image in the array. Am I able to give the images in the array and id so that I can have the function change to that id image

Comment: So if you wanted to access the first image when someone clicks feed, you would just do `target.src = myRhino[0];`

Comment: @Katie.Sun So If I want to target the 5th image it would be target.src = myRhino [4] ;

Comment: that is correct

Comment: @Katie.Sun Ok thank you for your help. I think that should make it easier for me to make a function that will occur when that button is clicked that will change to the picture that I chose. Thanks Again!

Comment: @Katie.Sun Another question that just came to me. If I click feed and do target.src = myRhino [1]; The picture changes to the second image.If I click the feed button again can I have that picture change to something else?

Comment: I think if you try it you will find that it will go to the picture after the one that was last selected in the `ChangePic()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've edited your question to a new question, I'll post an additional answer.

The reason as to why your timer isn't working is because you have a few issues with your code:

- `myVar = setTimeout("TimeoutImg()",2000);` isn't correct, your first argument for `setTimeout` should be a function callback, not a string. Here you've almost got it right, you just need to change your string to the function callback:

  `var myVar = setTimeout(TimeoutImg, 2000);`

  Also, generally in programming, it's not considered "good practice" to name your functions with capital letters at the start (as you use capitals for classes/objects). So from now on, I will use lowercase letters at the start of each function name.
- Another issue is how you are stopping the timeout interval. You've
  got the right idea with having `onlcick` trigger the `timeoutStop`
  function, however, you're not going about it the right way. A HTML
  element should only have no repeated attributes on it, so in your
  case, you're repeating `onclick` twice:

  `onclick="timeoutStop()" onclick="changeImage(this)"`

  Instead, of having two `onclick` attributes, you can combine these into one:

  `onclick="changeImage(this); timeoutStop()"`

Fixing these issues will resolve your issue.

See working example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>

  <center>
    <b> This is My Virtual Pet!</b>
  </center>
  <center> <img id="target" src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/14623/images/magazine_hero/WW188829.jpg?1509653431" width="300" height="250" />

    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage()" value=" Scroll Through Emotions" /> </center>

  <br>
  <center>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(this); timeoutStop()" data-values="1,2" value="Feed">
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(this); timeoutStop()" data-values="3,4,5" value="Pet">
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(this); timeoutStop()" data-values="3,0,4" value="Play">
  </center>


  <script>
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var counter = 0;
    var myRhino = [
      "https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/14623/images/magazine_hero/WW188829.jpg?1509653431",

      "https://img04.deviantart.net/0594/i/2010/261/5/6/happy_rhino_by_ammut88-d2z0sto.jpg",

      "https://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large-5/angry-rhino-daniel-eskridge.jpg",

      "https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1340/1368093048_fa7ef85a5a_z.jpg?zz=1",

      "https://images.fineartamerica.com/images/artworkimages/mediumlarge/1/hungry-rhino-james-sarjeant.jpg",

      "http://m.rgbimg.com/cache1nulfB/users/z/za/zatrokz/600/meRoKDQ.jpg",

      "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R_zz1GEkEk4/maxresdefault.jpg",
    ];

    var changeImageTimer = setTimeout(timeoutImg, 5000); // 5 second timer

    function changeImage(btn) {
      if (!btn) {
        counter += 1;
        target.src = myRhino[counter % myRhino.length];
      } else {
        var data = btn.getAttribute('data-values');
        var pics = JSON.parse("[" + data + "]"); // Convert string of numbers to an array
        var num = pics.shift(); // remove index 0 from array and store it in num
        pics.push(num); // Add what was previously at index 0 to end of array
        target.src = myRhino[num];
        counter = num;
        btn.setAttribute('data-values', pics.join(','));
      }
    }

    function timeoutImg() {
      target.src = myRhino[myRhino.length-1];
    }

    function timeoutStop() {
      clearTimeout(changeImageTimer);
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need one function to achieve this. Firstly, you can create a function which is in charge of changing the pictures, which you currently have. In my example below I called this `changeImage`. This function can accept `this` as an argument, which refers to the current button you clicked on.

```
onclick="changeImage(this);" // When button is clicked, go to image at index 2
```

By using `this` we can get the button's attributes such as the `data-values` attribute I defined on your buttons.

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="1,2" value="Feed">
```

The `data-values` attribute allows you to specify the images you want to go to on each image click and the order in which it should follow. I made the `data-values` attribute work by:

- Converting the string value to an array of numbers. Eg: `"1,2"` turns into `[1, 2]`. This allows me to manipulate the values easily.
- Using this array, I then get the value at index 0 using `.shift()`. This removes the value at index `0` and also returns it. After using `.shift()` my array now looks like:
  `[2]`.
- However, because I used `.shift()` I was able to store the deleted value in `num`, which I use as the index for the image to display.
- I then use `.push()` to push the deleted value (or num) back onto the end of my array. So it now looks like `[2, 1]`.
- Lastly, I updated the `data-values` attribute to be equal to this new array. I use `.join(',')` on the array to turn it into "2,1", and then use `.setAttribute` to update my `data-values` attribute. So my element now looks like:

  `<input type="button" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="2,1" value="Feed">`

Now, if I click on the button again, I will repeat this cycle, and the image displayed will be `2` and the `data-values` attribute will be updated to `data-values="1,2"` again.

However, if a button isn't passed through into the function, (detected by using `if(!btn)`), then you can simply just change the image based on the counter.

See working example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>

  <center>
    <b> This is My Virtual Pet!</b>
  </center>
  <center> <img id="target" src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/14623/images/magazine_hero/WW188829.jpg?1509653431" width="300" height="250" />

    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage()" value=" Scroll Through Emotions" /> </center>

  <br>
  <center>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="1,2" value="Feed">
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="3,4,5" value="Pet">
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="3,0,4" value="Play">
  </center>


  <script>
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var counter = 0;
    var myRhino = [
      "https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/14623/images/magazine_hero/WW188829.jpg?1509653431",

      "https://img04.deviantart.net/0594/i/2010/261/5/6/happy_rhino_by_ammut88-d2z0sto.jpg",

      "https://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large-5/angry-rhino-daniel-eskridge.jpg",

      "https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1340/1368093048_fa7ef85a5a_z.jpg?zz=1",

      "https://images.fineartamerica.com/images/artworkimages/mediumlarge/1/hungry-rhino-james-sarjeant.jpg",

      "http://m.rgbimg.com/cache1nulfB/users/z/za/zatrokz/600/meRoKDQ.jpg",

      "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R_zz1GEkEk4/maxresdefault.jpg",
    ];

    function changeImage(btn) {
      if (!btn) {
        counter += 1;
        target.src = myRhino[counter % myRhino.length];
      } else {
        var data = btn.getAttribute('data-values');
        var pics = JSON.parse("[" + data + "]"); // Convert string of numbers to an array
        var num = pics.shift(); // remove index 0 from array and store it in num
        pics.push(num); // Add what was previously at index 0 to end of array
        target.src = myRhino[num];
        counter = num;
        btn.setAttribute('data-values', pics.join(','));
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: When I click feed I want it to switch to a specific image and if I click it again I want it to change to another specific image. I added to my code a function that will get called and the code             target.src = myRhino[1]; I now want to be able to click the button again and have that image change to something else. What would I have to include to do that or can I do that with the code you showed?

Comment: @adilisi so you want to specify a collection of images that feed can change the image to? Eg: [2, 3, 5], so when I click on feed once, it will go to image 2, then if I click on it again, it will go to image 3, and if I click on it for a third time, it will go to image 5 ?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes what you said. I want to click feed and have it change to image 1 (or the second link) then if I click feed again have it change to image 2 (third Link). Then if I click Pet I want to change to another image then if I click pet again have it change from eg:[1,4,5]

Comment: @adilisi ok, I see, give me a few minutes to adjust my answer... if you click feed again (for the third time) do you want it to go back to image 1 or stop changing the images?

Comment: I will click feed once to change to an image then I want to click it again to change to a second image then a third time to change to another image, then a fourth to change to starting image.

Comment: @adilisi ok, see my updated answer. Read the code comments for a further explanation

Comment: @NickParsons ok thanks for all your help. I am going to look over your code and keep working on this. If I need anything else I may tag you again and ask another question if that is alright.

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks for your help. I think that the last thing that I want to add would be a timeout function. So I want to start a timer for 5 seconds when page opens and if no button is clicked have it change to the last image. The code I wrote so far looks like the code that I pasted above into my post.

Comment: @adilisi Hey, I've added a new answer to your new question, sorry for the late reply

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you soooo much for your help. I really appreciate it and you explaining everything helps a lot.

Comment: @adilisi no worries, glad to help :)